# php drop down menu will not keep selcted value

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu, html

On one of my pages I have a dynamic drop down menu. I have been able to connect to my DB but I have an issue: when I select a value in the list it Defaults back to `Pick emission`. **How can I program the drop down menu to retain the last seleciton?**

I think I am missing something obvious — here is the code I am running:

```
<p><form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
My Mission Today is:
<select Emission Name='NEW'>
<option value="">---Select emission ---</option>
<option class="option" value="Patience">Patience</option> 
<option class="option" value="Hope">Hope</option>
<option class="option" value="Strength">Strength</option>
<option class="option" value="Boundaries">Boundaries</option>
</select>

<?php
   mysql_connect ("localhost","user_name","Password");
   mysql_select_db ("my_database");
   $select="emission";
   if (isset ($select)&&$select!=""){
   $select=$_POST ['NEW'];
 }?>   


     <?php
       $list=mysql_query("SELECT *FROM`emission`ORDERBY`emission`.`emission_id`ASC     LIMIT 0 , 30");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($list)){
     ?>

        <option value="<? echo $row['emission_id']; ?>"
           <? if($row['emission_id']==$select){ echo "selected"; } ?>>
           <?echo $row['emission_name'];?>
        </option>


        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Select" />
</form></p>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly, have the menu retain the selected value? Can you edit your post into the form of a question. Thanks

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_*` functions anymore because they're deprecated and get removed very soon. Please use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead to future proof your script.

Comment: your while loop is not closed.

Comment: … and you are outputting `option` elements outside of the `select` element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rethink your code.

```
$select="emission";
if ( isset ($select)&&$select!=""
```

This is a pointless `if` statement, because `$select` is set on the previous line. You then set `$select` again on the next line...

```
$select=$_POST ['NEW'];
```

There's also a bunch of other stuff wrong, like having `Emission` in your `<option>` tag, and not using spaces in random places like `ORDER BY`, but I won't go into that, other than: try to make your code more readable.

What it boils down to is quite simple, though. In your `while` loop, insert this:

```
$selected = $_POST['NEW'] == $row['emission_id'] ? 'selected' : '';
```

Then put this `$selected` variable inside your option, like so:

```
<option <?php echo $selected; ?>
```